# Allow user to pick a number with each taxonomy term

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

Example:
I have several vocabularies each one representing animals:
First vocab: Dogs (child terms are breeds)
Second vocab: Cats (child terms are breeds)

So user for example has 6 golden retrievers, and he picks the term "Golden retriever". Now he should be able to pick how many he has, so i need a number to pick next to each term.

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typical [Field Collection](http://drupal.org/project/field_collection) case.

Have fun !